# Does Symmetry breaking happen in $SU(N)$-Anderson model in large-$N$ limit?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, path-integral, mean-field-theory, strong-correlated

Consider the following $SU(N)$-Anderson model,

$$H = \epsilon_{}^{}\sum_{\sigma=1}^{N} c_{\sigma}^{\dagger}c_{\sigma}^{}+\sum_{\sigma=1}^{N}\sum_{k}^{}\epsilon_{k}^{}d_{k\sigma}^{\dagger}d_{k \sigma}^{} + \sum_{\sigma=1}^{N}\sum_{k}^{}\left[g_{k}^{}d_{k\sigma}^{\dagger}c_{\sigma}^{}+g_{k}^{*}c_{\sigma}^{\dagger}d_{k\sigma}^{}\right]+\frac{U}{2 N}\sum_{\sigma,\sigma^\prime=1}^{N}c_{\sigma}^{\dagger}c_{\sigma^\prime}^{\dagger}c_{\sigma^\prime}^{}c_{\sigma}^{},$$
where $\{c_{\sigma}^{\dagger},c_{\sigma}^{},d_{k\sigma}^{\dagger},d_{k\sigma}^{}\}$ are a set of fermionic operators. The index $\sigma$ corresponds to the flavor quantum number and the index $k$ spans over the continuum of metallic states.

Impurity contribution to the partition function is given as the following functional integral over grassman fields,

$$\mathcal{Z}_{\text{imp}}^{}=\int_{\{\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\beta)=-\psi_{\sigma}^{}(0)\}}^{}\mathbb{D}[\{\psi_{\sigma}^{\dagger}(\tau),\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\tau)\}]\ \ e_{}^{-\mathcal{S}_{\text{imp}^{}}^{}[\{\psi_{\sigma}^{\dagger}(\tau),\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\tau)\}]},$$

with
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathcal{S}_{\text{imp}^{}}^{}[\{\psi_{\sigma}^{\dagger}(\tau),\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\tau)\}] =\nonumber\\
&&\sum_{\sigma=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau^\prime\ \ \psi_{\sigma}^{\dagger}(\tau)\left\{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}+\left(\epsilon_{}^{}-\mu_{}^{}\right)\right]\delta(\tau-\tau^\prime)-\Sigma_{}^{}(\tau-\tau^\prime)\right\}\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\tau^\prime)\nonumber\\
&&+\frac{U}{2 N}\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau\left[\sum_{\sigma=1}^{N}\psi_{\sigma}^{\dagger}(\tau)\psi_{\sigma}^{}(\tau)\right]_{}^{2},\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
where $\Sigma_{}^{}(\tau-\tau^\prime)=\sum_{k}^{}|g_{k}^{}|_{}^{2}e_{}^{-\left(\epsilon_{k}^{}-\mu_{}^{}\right)\left(\tau-\tau^\prime\right)}\left\{\Theta(\tau-\tau^\prime)\left[1-f_{}^{}(\epsilon_{k}^{})\right]-\Theta(\tau^\prime-\tau)f_{}^{}(\epsilon_{k}^{})\right\}$ (where $f_{}^{}(\epsilon_{k}^{})=\left(e_{}^{\beta\left(\epsilon_{k}^{}-\mu_{}^{}\right)}+1\right)_{}^{-1}$) is the self-energy of impurity due to hybridization with the metal states. Note: $\Theta[\tau],\delta(\tau)$ are periodic generalizations of standard functions.

Using Hubbard-Stratanovich transformation and integrating out impurity fermion grassman fields one obtains the **interaction** contribution to the partition function (exploiting $SU(N)$-symmetry),

$$\mathcal{Z}_{\text{int}}^{}=\frac{1}{\mathcal{N}}\int_{\mathbb{\Phi}(\beta)=\mathbb{\Phi}(0)}^{}\mathbb{D}[\{\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\}]e_{}^{-N \mathcal{S}_{}^{}[\{\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\}]},$$

where
$$\mathcal{S}_{}^{}[\{\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\}]= \frac{U}{2}\int_{0}^{\beta}\left[\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\right]_{}^{2}+\mathbf{Tr}\log\left[\delta(\tau-\tau^\prime)+i U \mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\mathbb{G}_{0}^{}(\tau-\tau^\prime)\right],$$

with $$\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau^{\prime\prime}\left\{\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}+\left(\epsilon_{}^{}-\mu_{}^{}\right)\right]\delta(\tau-\tau^{\prime\prime})-\Sigma_{}^{}(\tau-\tau^{\prime\prime})\right\}\mathbb{G}_{0}^{}(\tau^{\prime\prime}-\tau^\prime)=\delta(\tau-\tau^\prime)$$ and $$\mathbb{G}_{0}^{}(\tau-\tau^\prime+\beta)=-\mathbb{G}_{0}^{}(\tau-\tau^\prime).$$

In the $N \to \infty$ limit, the interaction contribution to the free energy (per flavor) can be evaluated using saddle point approximation as,

$$F_{\text{int}}^{}=\beta_{}^{-1} \mathcal{S}_{}^{}[\{\mathbb{\Phi}_{0}^{}(\tau)\}],$$
with $\mathbb{\Phi}_{0}^{}(\tau)$ the solution of $$\frac{\delta}{\delta \mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)}\mathcal{S}_{}^{}[\{\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)\}]\Bigg|_{\{\mathbb{\Phi}(\tau)=\mathbb{\Phi}_{0}^{}(\tau)\}}^{}=0.$$

Assuming this stationary path to be independent of $\tau$, one arrives at the time-independent mean field (gap) equation (assuming wide band approximation gives analytical form of the equation), first obtained by Anderson for $N=2$ case at $\beta_{}^{-1}=0$. As Anderson notes, for this case, there is a stable solution below $U_{c}^{}$, above which  pitch forth bifurcation happens and two spin symmetry breaking stable solutions appear. This symmetry breaking was later shown to be an artefact of mean field approximation. In the present $N \to \infty$ case, mean-field seems to be become exact. My confusion lies here, how to interpret the solution of mean-field equation (which is unique) above $U_{c}^{}$, where it is unstable. Is there any symmetry breaking transition happening here? Is this variant of Anderson model studied already? What is the physics above $U_{c}^{}$?